# django static file : The requested resource was not found on this server

Tags: django

my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>

<head>
    <title>Fish store</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/animate.css' %}">
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Home page</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'fish.apps.FishConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

in fish app I have static folder and css folder, and then animate.css
fish/static/css/animate.css

main url

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.index)
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Now I try to access http://localhost:8000/static/css/animate.css

it shows:

```
Not Found
The requested resource was not found on this server.
```

Comment: Where is animate.css located? Can you share your settings for STATICFILES_DIRS  and STATICFILES_FINDERS

Comment: @Iain Shelvington it's all default, it's a new project, i have defined only STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT , i have updated my question

Comment: Where is animate.css located?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington it's in my new app called fish, like this fish/static/css/animate.css

Comment: Can you share STATICFILES_DIRS and STATICFILES_FINDERS on settings.py ?